# Why does Intellij not like my Gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, multi-module

We have a Gradle v6.8.2 multimodule project that is structured like this:

```
.
├── searchapi
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── searchcommon
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── searchconfig
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── searchindexer
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── settings.gradle
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

The child modules have a number of overlapping dependencies (e.g. `commons-lang`) and we are specifying the version of these dependencies within the parent `build.gradle` using variables like this:

`ext.commonslangversion = "[2,3)"`

Then, within the child projects, we specify the dependency like this:

`implementation "commons-lang:commons-lang:${commonslangversion}"`

The top-level build itself works great from the CLI and within Intellij (v2022.1.4).

The issue I'm having is when I try to run code within one of the child projects from Intellij. Specifically, within the `searchindexer` module, I have a class that contains a `main()` method. When I right click and choose to run this method, I get a build error that says:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'searchindexer'.
> Could not get unknown property 'commonslangversion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Any thoughts?

To further confuse things, if I move the body of the `main()` method into one of my JUnit test class methods and execute the test from within Intellij, it builds and runs fine. WTF!

Comment: If it's reproducible in the current release version, I'd report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a sample project and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: For posterity: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#naming_recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a gradle multiproject build, you must have only one `settings.gradle` script, located in the root project level. Here you have put one settings file under each subprojec, so neither gradle nor intellij will consider this as a multiproject build:  subprojects will be treated as standalone projects, and will not inherit configuration or properties set on root project level.

just remove `settings.gradle` files from subprojects.